# password data not appear in edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a problem

in edit mode i bring user data and all data come normally

then i add that data to text fields on the page and that also work well

I'm sure from that as i see it in debug mode

but when the page come to the browser the password field is empty although i put the data on it

can any one tell me where is the problem ???

that is the code

method get data from data base

```
public AdminsContianer getContainer(int adminId)
{
    using (Naqqab context = new Naqqab())
    {
        IQueryable<user> admin = getContainer_compiledQuery2.Invoke(context, adminId);
        if (admin.Count() > 0)
        {
            var add = admin.FirstOrDefault();
            if (add != null)
            {
                var rc = new AdminsContianer();
                rc.FirstName = add.user_firstname;
                rc.adminCreationdate = (DateTime)add.user_creationdate;
                rc.LastName = add.user_lastname;
                rc.Username = add.user_username;
                rc.Password = add.user_password;
                rc.adminLuState = add.user_lu_status.ToString();
                rc.adminLuType = add.user_lu_type.ToString();
                rc.adminLevel = add.admin_level.ToString();
                rc.adminId = add.user_id;
                return rc;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

method put data in text fields

```
public void FillFormFields(AdminsContianer ad)
{
    HiddenAdminID.Value = AdminIdToEdit;
    registerAdminUsername.Text = ad.Username;
    registerAdminLastname.Text = ad.LastName;
    registerAdminFirstname.Text = ad.FirstName;
    registerAdminPassword.Text = ad.Password;
    registerAdminCPassword.Text = ad.Password;
    adminLevelDropDownList.SelectedValue = ad.adminLevel.ToString();
    //userTypeDropDownList.SelectedValue = ad.adminLuType.ToString();
    registerAdminState.SelectedValue = ad.adminLuState.ToString();
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: change your `<asp:TextBox TextMode="password"` to `<input type="password" runat="server" id="someid" />`

Comment: Why would you like to show values in the password file. Because user can't read it anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to set value in password  textbox `registerAdminPasswod.Attributes.Add("value", ad.Password);`

Comment: thanks very much it works well 
i want to mark it as answer and vote it up but i have no enough reputation

Answer (score 2):

Why would you like to show the password because it can't be understand by the user.
Here is a solution its a code project link which has the [solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18087/ASP-NET-Password-TextBox)

or

```
txt1.Text = "sample_password";
if (txt1.TextMode == TextBoxMode.Password)
{
    txt1.Attributes.Add("value", txt1.Text);
}
```

Comment: thanks very much that code works well
and for your question i need to view it as if he click save agian without changing his old password the system should save the old one 
if i left it empty there will be an error 
so i only used
txt1.Attributes.Add("value", txt1.Text);
and it works well

Comment: If user has left the password field blank don't update this filed in the database.